# Comma before a clause without subject

Tags: sentence-construction

> After a Saudi gunman killed three people at a naval base in Pensacola, Fla., some of President Trump’s Republican allies took to the airwaves to condemn the attack as an act of terrorism, call for a halt to the training program that admitted the shooter and sharply press the Saudi government to cooperate in the investigation.

1. Which is the subject for the clause "call for ...." ?
2. Why use a comma before "call" ?
3. Is OK to rephrase "to condemn the attack as an act of terrorism" to " to condemn the attack and calling it as an act of terrorism" ?

Comment: It's an example of a list. Similar to:  "Amy likes to swim, go to the gym, eat apples and bake cakes."

Answer (score 0):

Good question, Aaa3090!

1 The allies.

2 Such lists are punctuated like this: "He carried a coat, his briefcase and an umbrella". "He did A, B, C, D and E."  The allies took to the airwaves to condemn, call and press.

3 No. You COULD say, "to condemn the attack and **call** it an act of terrorism" or "**condemning** the attack and calling it an act of terrorism". To condemn and [to] call are both infinitives. Condemning and calling are present participles. They need to match.

You could however rewrite the whole sentence: "...allies took to the airwaves condemn**ing** the attack as an act of terrorism, call**ing** for a halt to the training program that admitted the shooter and sharply press**ing** the Saudi government to cooperate in the investigation." [As a matter of fact this is slightly better than the original, which contains an implied split infinitive: *to sharply press*. Split infinitives are beyond the scope of this answer!]

Comment: "call" has no subject because it is infinitive.